# Finding all solutions for $3^c=2^a+2^b+1$

Tags: number-theory

Given the equation:

$3^c=2^a+2^b+1$

Find all solutions for $a,b,c$ - given that they are positive integers and $b>a$.

Any ideas?

Comment: Only solution seems to be $3^4=2^4+2^6+1$. But cannot see how to prove it. The number of 1s in the binary expansion of $3^c$ seems to increase, although not monotonically. But it should be possible to show it is greater than 3 for $c>4$.

Comment: yes that's kind of intuitive guess. i'm stuck too.

Comment: Pillai has solved this equation for all integers in $1945$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's still relatively simple to handle such exponential equations using local arguments. If $a \geq 5$, then we have $3^c \equiv 1 \pmod{32}$ and hence $8 \mid c$. It follows that $3^c \equiv 1 \pmod{41}$ and so $2^{b-a} \equiv -1 \pmod{41}$. We therefore have $b-a \equiv 10 \pmod{20}$ which implies that $2^{b-a} \equiv -1 \pmod{25}$ and $3^c \equiv 1 \pmod{25}$, whereby $5 \mid c$ and $2^{b-a} \equiv -1 \pmod{11}$. This last congruence implies that $b-a \equiv 5 \pmod{10}$, contradicting the parity of $b-a$.

The cases where $a=0, 2$ and $4$ are (more) easily treated (leading to the solutions with $(a,b)=(0,0), (2,2)$ and $(4,6)$).

Comment: how do you treat the other cases of $a=0,2,4$? and thank you for your answer.

Comment: If $a$ or $b$ is $0$, then parity implies that $a=b=0$. If $a=2$, then we have the equation $3^c-2^b=5$, which has no solutions with $b \geq 3$, modulo $8$. If $a=4$, note that $b=2b_0$ and $c=2c_0$ are even and factor $3^{2c_0}-2^{2b_0}=17$.

Answer (score 6):

This equation can be solved using Baker's method. It is explained in the book [Unsolved problems in number theory](https://books.google.at/books?id=1AP2CEGxTkgC&pg=PA242&lpg=PA242&dq=exponential+Diophantine+equation+3%5Ex%3D2%5Ey%2B2%5Ez%2B1&source=bl&ots=Tknvc0FMrB&sig=BGY4nmluGglIXGN7IktKfU7S3Ig&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjQmd7FisHMAhUCwBQKHYeFC4w4ChDoAQhmMAk#v=onepage&q=exponential%20Diophantine%20equation%203%5Ex%3D2%5Ey%2B2%5Ez%2B1&f=false) by Richard Guy. He writes "In fact, neither $3^a=1 +2^b+2^c$ nor $2^a+3^b=2^c+3^d$ can be reduced to a single congruence. But Baker's method makes it possible to solve these last two (exponential) Diophantine equations." Then he gives the relevant bibliography where this has been done.
In fact, the solution is attributed to Pillai. All integer solutions of $3^a=1 +2^b+2^c$ are
$$
(a,b,c)=(1,0,0),(2,2,2),(4,6,4),(4,4,6).
$$

S.S. Pillai: On the equation $2^x-3^y=2^z+3^w$, Bull. Calcutta Math. Soc. $37$, 1945.

Comment: thank you, i didn't find the actual bibliography .

Comment: Dear Matt, Pillai's proof is discussed in other papers, too. There are several papers discussing exponential Diophantine equations of this type, with generalisations.

Comment: Thank you Dietrich, i look into it.

Answer (score -2):

working in $\pmod3$ we find that 
$0=(-1)^a+(-1)^b+1 \pmod3$

$edit;$

it only shows that $a$ and $b$ must be even, in $\pmod4$ we see that $c$ also must be even

Comment: $3^4=2^4+2^6+1$

Comment: What about $a=b=2$? That solves the modular equation.

Comment: but $b>a$ see my question

Comment: this only means that a and b must be even.